# Selecting posts with multiple tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm implementing a tagging system on a blog app. This app has posts, posts have many tags through taggings. More or less like RailCasts #382 http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

I will use checkboxes to select posts with multiple tags like this:

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(:tags => { :id => [tag_ids] } )
```

But what if I want to join posts that have all the required tags instead of posts that meet only one requirements?

For exapmle:

Post1 has tags "foo, bar, baz"

Post2 has tags "bar, baz"

Post3 has tags "bar"

If I search for ["bar", "baz"] my method returns posts 1, 2 and 3. What If I want to return only post 1 and 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, you would do something like

```
GROUP BY posts.id
HAVING count(tags.name) = 2
```

In rails it translates to

```
Post.joins(:tags).select('posts.id').where(:tags => { :id => [tag_ids] }
).having("count(tags.name) = ?", tag_ids.count).group('posts.id')
```

The above code assumes that `tag_ids` is an array of ids. Also, it only loads the ids for the returned set of ActiveRecord Post objects.

If you want to load more fields, add them in the `select` call, or otherwise remove the `select` call to load all Post fields. Just remember that for every column/field from Post that is retrieved in the resulting SQL query, you will need to add that field to the `group` call.

Comment: This works fine. Anyway tag_ids.count returns NameError: undefined local variable or method `tag_ids' for main:Object

Comment: I assumed tag_ids was an array. I'm guessing it might be a string in the format of "id0,id1,id2". If that's the case, you can do tag_ids.split(",").count to get the number that it needs to match.