# How can I filter products by multiple categories with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'd like to add the ability to filter products by multiple categories to a Rails ecommerce application. I currently allow filtering products by category, but now I'd like to provide the ability to filter further.

For example, I'd like to allow a user to select "Men's" and "Outerwear" to display only products in both of those categories.

Knowing that supplying an array of category IDs in my Product query will find products in any of the specified categories, and hoping for a nice ActiveRecord-y type solution, I first tried adding multiple `categories.id` conditions in the query, but this didn't work out.

```rb
Product.joins(:categories).where(:'categories.id' => 123, :'categories.id' => 456)
```

The result here was that the first category ID was overwritten by the second.

And, of course, this will find products in either of the categories, rather than only products in both:

```rb
Product.joins(:categories).where(:'categories.id' => [123, 456])
```

Additionally, the solution I need should work with an arbitrary number of categories. It could be two, it could be three, or more.

After doing some research, I don't think there's a nice Rails-y way to do this, but I'm stuck on finding the actual correct solution.

My application is running Rails 5.2 with MariaDB.

Comment: So you want products with *both* categories? BTW, `:'categories.id' => 123, :'categories.id' => 456` doesn't work because that's really a Hash literal and Hashes don't repeat keys.

Comment: Are you looking for `where(categories: { id: [123,456] })`?

Comment: @Iceman No, that will find products in either of the two categories. I need to find only products that are in both.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, that's correct. Products that are in both (or all 3, or however many) categories. Good point about the hash keys; that was just the first thing to come to mind and I didn't think too much about _why_ it didn't work.

Comment: I'm just stepping out but you want to look at the SQL "HAVING" clause combined with a `COUNT`: `where id in (1,2,3) ... having count(*) = 3` sort of thing. Search around for things about "having all tags" to get an idea.

Comment: Is it many to many relationship between product and category? How are you storing the categories for each product in model?

Comment: @Kenn : `Product.joins(:categories).where(:'categories.id' => 123).where(:'categories.id' => 456)` does chaining the where clauses work?

Comment: @ChiragShah That actually returns 0 results, when it should return 1. I expected it to behave the same as including both in a single `where()` clause but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @dharmesh Product and Category both have a HABTM relation with the other, and the product/category data is stored in a `products_categories` join table.

Comment: @muistooshort Good tip, thanks. I'll look into that.

Comment: if it's a join table where every product has one row per category, you would need to build a join query where the products_categories is joined twice, so for each category you are looking for. you will have to dedup the result. since this is quite ugly, i would probably go with a subquery.

Comment: @muistooshort With your tip I found exactly what I needed. I'll update my post with my answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @muistooshort's comment above, I found this SO post with the solution I needed:
[Selecting posts with multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569873/selecting-posts-with-multiple-tags)

Updating my query like so gave the products I wanted, those in ALL of the specified categories (lines wrapped for readability):

```rb
Product.joins(:categories).where(:categories => { :id => category_ids })
    .having('count(categories.name) = ?', category_ids.size)
    .group('products.id')
```